# How to close the space between two elements

Tags: html

I am trying to close the gap between my top two elements (an h1 tag and an image tag which is wrapped in a link tag).

I've tried changing margins and floating... I'm stuck :(

```
<div align="center">
    <h1 style="color:blue; background-color:lightgrey; font-size:100px;">Inner Planets - Museum</h1>

    <a href="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/museum.html"><img src="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/images/Banner1.jpg" height="400" width="1250"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Simply update the margin/padding styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And another style to h1 element in order to close the space.

Add **margin-bottom:10px** in style of h1.

```
 <h1 style="color:blue; background-color:lightgrey; margin-bottom:10px; font-size:100px;">Inner Planets - Museum</h1>
```

Here is a plunker for same - http://plnkr.co/edit/1zvOxIar7RQOVcwmKV7B?p=preview